# How to write correct IF formula in excel? if value=smth, write next value

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I need a help with excel formula.

So, I have a list of values in column A, for example this list:
[list in column A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI78X.png)

I need to exclude "snickers" and "ticket" from the list and write the next value instead. So, if the value in the column A is "snickers" or "ticket", I need to write the next value.
This formula came to my mind, but it is not working:
=IF(OR(A1="snickers";A1="ticket");A2;A1)

It writes the next value after "tickets" or "snickers" twice...

Here is the example:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF9SO.png)

Can you please help me to correct the formula?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need something like this copy-paste down in Column B

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1))="snickers",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1))="ticket"),A2,A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your attached image actually shows your cell contents ('1 mouse', '2 cat', '6 snickers', '10 ticket' etc.) then your ="ticket" or ="snickers" will not work.  You could use `OR(RIGHT(A1, 8)="snickers", RIGHT(A1,6="ticket")`

I'm guessing that your image is more for reference than depicting the actual cell contents, however you can use RIGHT(A1) or not as required.

You can make use of the offset function to 'write the next value', however the caveat is that if there are 2 adjacent cells that have "snickers" and "ticket" next to each other, it will return "snickers" or "ticket" depending on which is below in row order.  If you want to code for that scenario, then you would need to nest further IF statements.

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(A1, 8)="snickers",RIGHT(A1, 6)="ticket"),OFFSET(B1,1,-1),OFFSET(B1,0,-1))
```

The formula above checks the contents of cell A1 for "snickers" or "ticket".  If the cell contains either, the value from the cell below `OFFSET(B1,1,-1)` (left one, down one) is returned.  If the cell does not contain either, then the adjacent cell `OFFSET(B1,0,-1)` (left one) is returned.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, but both of your formulas are doing the same thing, just like my formula.
Numbers 1, 2, 3 etc. was just for referencing the cells, it is not important.
I tried both of yours formulas and I am getting double values again:

[first formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H0pQ.png)

And here is second formula:
[second formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMKBW.png)

This is what I want to achive [i want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY1j7.png)